# The argument type 'ModalRoute<Object?>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PageRoute<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

Recently I am migrating to null safety. Updated the firebase_analytics: ^8.0.2.

Now facing problem with this.observer.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)); Can some one help what to pass second argument.

```
class _BookedClassDetailsPageState extends 
State<BookedClassDetailsPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, RouteAware{

late FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 observer=widget.repository.analyticsService.getAnalyticsObserver();
 observer.analytics.setCurrentScreen(
     screenName: 'Booked Class Page',
     screenClassOverride: 'BookedClassPage'
 );

}

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  observer.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
}
 @override
 void dispose() {
    observer.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
 }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6095

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can change the type ModalRoute to PageRoute via key word "as", like this：

```
observer.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);
```